# Sharing state across Bloc

Tags: flutter, state-management, flutter-bloc

In my project I am using flutter_bloc library.

I have many screens, for each screen I am using `ScreenBloc<ScreenEvent, ScreenState>` and it works nice.

However, I am finding myself duplicating States classes such as Init Loading, Error, Loaded ShowBottomSheet etc' across these blocs.

Is there an elegant way or pattern to have some base States so all the blocs will share or extend?

Consider the following example:

```
 //For screen A I define the following: 
 class ScreenAEvent extends Equatable{}
 //Screen A events..
 
//Screen A states..
 class ScreenAState extends Equatable{}
 class Init extends ScreenAState{}
 class Loading extends ScreenAState{}
 class Error extends ScreenAState{
      final Exception e;
      Error(this.e)
 }
 class ShowBottomSheet extends ScreenAState{} //Using BlocListener to show bottom sheet
 class BlocScreenA extends Bloc<ScreenAEvent, ScreenAState>{
  //Code for screen A bloc
 }

 //For screen B I define the following: 
 class ScreenBEvent extends Equatable{}
 //Screen B events..
 
 //Screen B states
 class ScreenBState extends Equatable{}
 class Init extends ScreenBState{} //Defining again Init
 class Loading extends ScreenBState{} //Defining again Loading
 class Error extends ScreenBState{  //Same for error
      final Exception e;
      Error(this.e)
 }
 class ShowBottomSheet extends ScreenBState{} 
 class BlocScreenB extends Bloc<ScreenBEvent, ScreenBState>{
  //Code for screen B bloc
 }

 For each screen in the app, I have at least the Init, Loading, Error and Loaded states.. 
How can these implemented with the flutter_bloc library?
```

Comment: Can you please share some code ?

Comment: I've updated my question with code example

Comment: have you found solution for this @MotiBartov

Comment: @Baraa Aljabban
Actually yes, I've created an abstract class BaseState<T> with Init<T>, Loading<T>, Next<T>({var data : T})  and Error<T> which inherit from it. 
Then the BLoC -> class MyBloc extends Bloc<ScreenEvent, BaseState<ScreenState>> 

Then in the Bloc - yield(Next(data: ScreenState)), yield(Loading()) etc'